# Django: Values_list returns id from choice field instead of name

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models

```
class Model1:
   my_Choices = ((1, val1), (2, val2))

   field1 = choice_field(my_Choices)
   field2 = charfield
```

and another model which has ManyToMany field

```
class Model2:
    field1 = ManytoMany(Model1, related_name='rel_model2')
    field2 = Charfield
```

Now I have a list of objects(queryset) of Model2.(or for sake of simplicity assume I have an object of second model )

now I do reverse filtering

```
Model2_obj.rel_model2.all()
```

OR (In my case)

```
Model2_obj.rel_model2.values_list('field1', flat=True)
```

this will return the list of ids from choices available in Model1(right?)
e.g. `[1L, 2L]`

instead if this I want name/value (I mean list of values from choices)
e.g. 
`['val1', 'val2']`,

I can do this by iterating over both id list and choice_list but can we do in a single ORM query/Pythonic way/efficient way?

Answer (score -1):

if you choose to use the values_list() function, then you'll have to do the lookup/conversion yourself.  (That's because Django is storing the number in the database, and not the string, and values_list() says "get me what is in the database".)  Doing the lookup is not hard -- you can create a dictonary as

```
my_choices_dict = dict(my_choices)
```

and use that.

Alternatively, if you get the full object, you can use the get_field1_display() method that is built into your model class.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/ and search for "get_FOO_display"